# Date formatting only available as root

Tags: bash, debian, date

I have a really weird behavior on both my RaspberryPi 3 and OrangePi 3 after upgrading them to Debian 10.
The date command works but I can't set my own formatting with a non-elevated user:

```
baprx@raspberrypi:~ $ date -d "1970-01-01"
01-01-1970 00:00:00

baprx@raspberrypi:~ $ date -d "1970-01-01" '+%Y-%m-%d'
date: extra operand ‘+%Y-%m-%d’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

If the command is ran logged as root or using sudo it works:

```
baprx@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo date -d "1970-01-01" '+%Y-%m-%d'
1970-01-01
```

Do you have any idea of what could cause that behavior?

```
baprx@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster

baprx@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:25:51 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

baprx@raspberrypi:~ $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

baprx@raspberrypi:~ $ which date
/bin/date
```

Answer (score -1):

The `date` command was an alias of `date` with some parameters, I still don't know why but after run `unalias date`, the command works as expected.